# Trouble with a Peavey XR 684

Tags: repair, setup, mixer, pa

So, i honestly got this as a Christmas present, along with a ton of stuff a musician left here before moving to Ecuador (Two JBL TR125, i don't know, PA? A pretty old Peavey amplifier that i honestly found too defective, and a Bass guitar, that also doesn't make any sound.)

So i was doing some testing with the XR684, and everything was going pretty well until i tried to plug a 1/4" stereo jack in the third channel stereo input. (I tried to wire a Microphone to this input)

It made a horrible sound, like a blast, so i unplugged it immediately and checked the audio again with a DVI to 3.5 mm stereo, i plugged the DVI side onto the "line in" input, and plugged the stereo end to my phone. (It had worked just fine before).

But then, the right PA wouldn't emit any audio.

I switched the right and left PAs to see if the one i was using as the right speaker was damaged, but it worked just fine. And the one that i was using as the left speaker, now plugged into the right output, now wouldn't emit any sounds.

I think it may be the output, then, probably affected by my mistake, but i don't know much of these kind of things, so i ask for advise before messing something up again.